# JavaFX Tab positioning on mouse drag/drop

Tags: javafx-2

I have a Tabpane with multiple tabs.
I want to re-position tabs by just dragging them at a particular position(just like the way we are able to arrange tabs in browser.)
Is there any way i can achieve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We achieved it in a slightly different way.Instead of drag/drop feature we provided the move left/move right functionality on tab context menu which in turns moves the tab.
We wanted to have this feature on priority so implemented it with this workaround for now.
[image]

## Code snippet for MoveRight:

```
public void moveRight() {
    protected TabPane workBook;
    int cTabIndex = bem.workBook.getTabs().indexOf(bem.activeSheet);
    int tabCount = workBook.getTabs().size();

    if (tabCount > 1 && cTabIndex > 0) {
        workBook.getTabs().remove(bem.activeSheet);
        workBook.getTabs().add(cTabIndex - 1, bem.activeSheet);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I've implemented a class that handles both draggable and detachable tabs - more details [here](http://berry120.blogspot.co.uk/2014/01/draggable-and-detachable-tabs-in-javafx.html). The implementation is not the tidiest, nor the most resilient but works pretty well for me in the simple cases I've tried so far. I've deliberately kept everything in the one class to make it easier for others to copy / use / modify as they see fit.

The basic concept that I'm using (arguably mis-using) is that the graphic you can set on a tab can be any node, not just an `ImageView` (or similar.) So instead of using the `setText()` on `Tab` directly, I'm not adding any text at all, just setting the graphic to be a `Label` containing the desired text. Now that the label is present in the tab header (and is pretty much the tab header spacially), that makes it much easier (and skin-independant) to grab the global co-ordinates of each tab header in the pane. From then it's just a case of some relatively simple positioning logic to work out when to detach tabs into a new window, when to re-add them and when to reorder them.

Of course, this isn't an ideal solution but unfortunately I haven't seen much else on the subject!

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Control;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;
import javafx.stage.WindowEvent;

/**
 * A draggable tab that can optionally be detached from its tab pane and shown
 * in a separate window. This can be added to any normal TabPane, however a
 * TabPane with draggable tabs must *only* have DraggableTabs, normal tabs and
 * DrragableTabs mixed will cause issues!
 * <p>
 * @author Michael Berry
 */
public class DraggableTab extends Tab {

    private static final Set<TabPane> tabPanes = new HashSet<>();
    private Label nameLabel;
    private Text dragText;
    private static final Stage markerStage;
    private Stage dragStage;
    private boolean detachable;

    static {
        markerStage = new Stage();
        markerStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        Rectangle dummy = new Rectangle(3, 10, Color.web("#555555"));
        StackPane markerStack = new StackPane();
        markerStack.getChildren().add(dummy);
        markerStage.setScene(new Scene(markerStack));
    }

    /**
     * Create a new draggable tab. This can be added to any normal TabPane,
     * however a TabPane with draggable tabs must *only* have DraggableTabs,
     * normal tabs and DrragableTabs mixed will cause issues!
     * <p>
     * @param text the text to appear on the tag label.
     */
    public DraggableTab(String text) {
        nameLabel = new Label(text);
        setGraphic(nameLabel);
        detachable = true;
        dragStage = new Stage();
        dragStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        StackPane dragStagePane = new StackPane();
        dragStagePane.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#DDDDDD;");
        dragText = new Text(text);
        StackPane.setAlignment(dragText, Pos.CENTER);
        dragStagePane.getChildren().add(dragText);
        dragStage.setScene(new Scene(dragStagePane));
        nameLabel.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
                dragStage.setWidth(nameLabel.getWidth() + 10);
                dragStage.setHeight(nameLabel.getHeight() + 10);
                dragStage.setX(t.getScreenX());
                dragStage.setY(t.getScreenY());
                dragStage.show();
                Point2D screenPoint = new Point2D(t.getScreenX(), t.getScreenY());
                tabPanes.add(getTabPane());
                InsertData data = getInsertData(screenPoint);
                if(data == null || data.getInsertPane().getTabs().isEmpty()) {
                    markerStage.hide();
                }
                else {
                    int index = data.getIndex();
                    boolean end = false;
                    if(index == data.getInsertPane().getTabs().size()) {
                        end = true;
                        index--;
                    }
                    Rectangle2D rect = getAbsoluteRect(data.getInsertPane().getTabs().get(index));
                    if(end) {
                        markerStage.setX(rect.getMaxX() + 13);
                    }
                    else {
                        markerStage.setX(rect.getMinX());
                    }
                    markerStage.setY(rect.getMaxY() + 10);
                    markerStage.show();
                }
            }
        });
        nameLabel.setOnMouseReleased(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
                markerStage.hide();
                dragStage.hide();
                if(!t.isStillSincePress()) {
                    Point2D screenPoint = new Point2D(t.getScreenX(), t.getScreenY());
                    TabPane oldTabPane = getTabPane();
                    int oldIndex = oldTabPane.getTabs().indexOf(DraggableTab.this);
                    tabPanes.add(oldTabPane);
                    InsertData insertData = getInsertData(screenPoint);
                    if(insertData != null) {
                        int addIndex = insertData.getIndex();
                        if(oldTabPane == insertData.getInsertPane() && oldTabPane.getTabs().size() == 1) {
                            return;
                        }
                        oldTabPane.getTabs().remove(DraggableTab.this);
                        if(oldIndex < addIndex && oldTabPane == insertData.getInsertPane()) {
                            addIndex--;
                        }
                        if(addIndex > insertData.getInsertPane().getTabs().size()) {
                            addIndex = insertData.getInsertPane().getTabs().size();
                        }
                        insertData.getInsertPane().getTabs().add(addIndex, DraggableTab.this);
                        insertData.getInsertPane().selectionModelProperty().get().select(addIndex);
                        return;
                    }
                    if(!detachable) {
                        return;
                    }
                    final Stage newStage = new Stage();
                    final TabPane pane = new TabPane();
                    tabPanes.add(pane);
                    newStage.setOnHiding(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {

                        @Override
                        public void handle(WindowEvent t) {
                            tabPanes.remove(pane);
                        }
                    });
                    getTabPane().getTabs().remove(DraggableTab.this);
                    pane.getTabs().add(DraggableTab.this);
                    pane.getTabs().addListener(new ListChangeListener<Tab>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onChanged(ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Tab> change) {
                            if(pane.getTabs().isEmpty()) {
                                newStage.hide();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    newStage.setScene(new Scene(pane));
                    newStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
                    newStage.setX(t.getScreenX());
                    newStage.setY(t.getScreenY());
                    newStage.show();
                    pane.requestLayout();
                    pane.requestFocus();
                }
            }

        });
    }

    /**
     * Set whether it's possible to detach the tab from its pane and move it to
     * another pane or another window. Defaults to true.
     * <p>
     * @param detachable true if the tab should be detachable, false otherwise.
     */
    public void setDetachable(boolean detachable) {
        this.detachable = detachable;
    }

    /**
     * Set the label text on this draggable tab. This must be used instead of
     * setText() to set the label, otherwise weird side effects will result!
     * <p>
     * @param text the label text for this tab.
     */
    public void setLabelText(String text) {
        nameLabel.setText(text);
        dragText.setText(text);
    }

    private InsertData getInsertData(Point2D screenPoint) {
        for(TabPane tabPane : tabPanes) {
            Rectangle2D tabAbsolute = getAbsoluteRect(tabPane);
            if(tabAbsolute.contains(screenPoint)) {
                int tabInsertIndex = 0;
                if(!tabPane.getTabs().isEmpty()) {
                    Rectangle2D firstTabRect = getAbsoluteRect(tabPane.getTabs().get(0));
                    if(firstTabRect.getMaxY()+60 < screenPoint.getY() || firstTabRect.getMinY() > screenPoint.getY()) {
                        return null;
                    }
                    Rectangle2D lastTabRect = getAbsoluteRect(tabPane.getTabs().get(tabPane.getTabs().size() - 1));
                    if(screenPoint.getX() < (firstTabRect.getMinX() + firstTabRect.getWidth() / 2)) {
                        tabInsertIndex = 0;
                    }
                    else if(screenPoint.getX() > (lastTabRect.getMaxX() - lastTabRect.getWidth() / 2)) {
                        tabInsertIndex = tabPane.getTabs().size();
                    }
                    else {
                        for(int i = 0; i < tabPane.getTabs().size() - 1; i++) {
                            Tab leftTab = tabPane.getTabs().get(i);
                            Tab rightTab = tabPane.getTabs().get(i + 1);
                            if(leftTab instanceof DraggableTab && rightTab instanceof DraggableTab) {
                                Rectangle2D leftTabRect = getAbsoluteRect(leftTab);
                                Rectangle2D rightTabRect = getAbsoluteRect(rightTab);
                                if(betweenX(leftTabRect, rightTabRect, screenPoint.getX())) {
                                    tabInsertIndex = i + 1;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                return new InsertData(tabInsertIndex, tabPane);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private Rectangle2D getAbsoluteRect(Control node) {
        return new Rectangle2D(node.localToScene(node.getLayoutBounds().getMinX(), node.getLayoutBounds().getMinY()).getX() + node.getScene().getWindow().getX(),
                node.localToScene(node.getLayoutBounds().getMinX(), node.getLayoutBounds().getMinY()).getY() + node.getScene().getWindow().getY(),
                node.getWidth(),
                node.getHeight());
    }

    private Rectangle2D getAbsoluteRect(Tab tab) {
        Control node = ((DraggableTab) tab).getLabel();
        return getAbsoluteRect(node);
    }

    private Label getLabel() {
        return nameLabel;
    }

    private boolean betweenX(Rectangle2D r1, Rectangle2D r2, double xPoint) {
        double lowerBound = r1.getMinX() + r1.getWidth() / 2;
        double upperBound = r2.getMaxX() - r2.getWidth() / 2;
        return xPoint >= lowerBound && xPoint <= upperBound;
    }

    private static class InsertData {

        private final int index;
        private final TabPane insertPane;

        public InsertData(int index, TabPane insertPane) {
            this.index = index;
            this.insertPane = insertPane;
        }

        public int getIndex() {
            return index;
        }

        public TabPane getInsertPane() {
            return insertPane;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I just found out that this has been implemented in JavaFX 10.

```
tabPane.tabDragPolicy = TabPane.TabDragPolicy.REORDER
```

...does the trick.

Answer (score 4):

*Update Feb 2016*

There is an open feature request you can use to track implementation:

- [JDK-8092098 [TabPane] Support for draggable tabs](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8092098)

The feature request is currently scheduled for implementation in Java 9.  Patches for obtaining drag and drop functionality are attached to the feature request.

---

Drag and Drop for tab headers is not implemented in the base JavaFX 2.2 platform.

Until that is implemented in the standard JDK, you will need to implement the feature yourself using JavaFX's [Drag and Drop functionality](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/drag_drop/jfxpub-drag_drop.htm).  A similar feature is implemented for dragging table column headers, so perhaps you could look to the [TableColumnHeader.java](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/tip/javafx-ui-controls/src/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/TableColumnHeader.java) code for inspiration in implementing your feature.

Should you implement it (if you wish) you can contribute the modifications back to [OpenJFX](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/OpenJDK/OpenJFX) via patches to the [TabSkin.java](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/tip/javafx-ui-controls/src/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/TabPaneSkin.java) source.

Comment: @Anshul, please create an answer that describes how you solved this.

Comment: I don't suppose you know of a better way of doing things in this regard now? I didn't find anything so created my own rudimentary solution (see my answer), but I'm aware that it definitely has it's pitfalls, so wondered if you'd come across any other external library that does this!

Comment: Sorry Berry, haven't seen anything.  It would be a nice feature to get into the core platform.

Answer (score 1):

A very descriptive answer can be found where you can create custom tabs for the same:

> http://0divides0.wordpress.com/2010/10/21/movable-tabbed-panes-in-javafx/

A JavaFX cooked solution is hard to find as dev blog for the same states that such functionality is not present for Tabs and they plan to incorporate later.

> http://grokbase.com/p/openjdk/openjfx-dev/123fq9k310/draggable-tabs

Answer (score 0):

The following code shows how to solve the problem in a very simple way without tricks.

```
 .....
    .....
    Tab tab1 = new Tab("Tab1");
    Tab tab2 = new Tab("Tab21");
    TabPane tabPane = new TabPane(tab1, tab21);
    root.getChildren().add(tabPane);
    ....
    ....
    System.out.println("Tabs size()= " + tabPane.lookupAll(".tab").size());
    tabPane.lookupAll(".tab").forEach(t -> {
         System.err.println("tab.bounds = " + t.getLayoutBounds());
    });
```

You can get an access to other areas of TabPane by using style classes such as tab-content-area, tab-header-area, tab-header-background, headers-region, control-buttons-tab. Just use lookup or lookupAll methods of TabPane