# How to drag and drop tabs of the SAME tabpane?

Tags: java, events, javafx, tabs, drag-and-drop

I've seen a lot on how to drag tabs of a tabpane to another, which by the way I don't see the point, I guess it can be useful to some extent but the most natural application should be to reorder tabs of the same tabpane, matter which nobody seems to talk about on the internet.

I'd like the behaviour that pretty much all the browsers have implemented.

I've tried something, but it's not doing what I want. The main problem comes from the fact that a `Tab` cannot be bound with the `setOnDragDetected`, `setOnDragOver` etc methods (for some reason that escapes me by the way ...) which results in overcomplicated algorithms to compensate this weakness of the library.

So here's my code, it's not doing what I want because (and it's only a workaround) I only detect the "drop target" AFTER the drop was made, thus making it useless. And yes, for SOME reason, hovering an object while holding the click button doesnt result in a `mouseover` event ...

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.input.ClipboardContent;
import javafx.scene.input.Dragboard;
import javafx.scene.input.TransferMode;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class DragAndDrop extends Application
{
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();

        final int[] target = {0};

        for(int i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i ++)
        {
            Tab tab = new Tab();
            tab.setClosable(false);

            int index[] = {i};

            tabPane.getTabs().add(tab);

            Label label = new Label("Tab " + (i + 1), new Rectangle(16, 16, Color.TRANSPARENT));
            tab.setGraphic(label);

            tab.getGraphic().setOnMouseEntered(event ->
            {
                target[0] = index[0];
                System.out.println("target : " + target[0]);
            });
        }

        tabPane.setOnDragDetected(event ->
        {
            Dragboard dragboard = tabPane.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.ANY);

            ClipboardContent clipboardContent = new ClipboardContent();
            clipboardContent.putString(Integer.toString(tabPane.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex()));
            System.out.println("source : " + tabPane.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex());
            dragboard.setContent(clipboardContent);

            event.consume();
        });

        tabPane.setOnDragOver(event ->
        {
            if(event.getDragboard().hasString())
            {
                event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.COPY_OR_MOVE);
            }

            event.consume();
        });

        tabPane.setOnDragDropped(event ->
        {
            Dragboard dragboard = event.getDragboard();
            boolean success = false;

            if(dragboard.hasString())
            {
                System.out.println("from " + dragboard.getString() + " to " + target[0]);

                success = true;
            }

            event.setDropCompleted(success);
            event.consume();
        });

        tabPane.setOnDragDone(event ->
        {
            if(event.getTransferMode() == TransferMode.MOVE)
            {
                // tabPane.setText("");
            }
            event.consume();
        });

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(tabPane, 300, 200));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the drag handlers directly on the tab graphics? I would think that would make the logic a bit cleaner. You wouldn't have to rely on the selection model in that case.

Comment: Unfortunatly this is not available yet in javafx ([see this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16437615/javafx-tab-positioning-on-mouse-drag-drop)). Although its pretty old (request link is for javafx-2.x), the webBlog link in the answer gives a nice explanation and an example on how you might want to accomplish your goal.

Comment: @James_D I don't think it would change anything to the problem since I still wouldn't be able to detect the hover of the second tab (the target) before the drop of the first tab (the source).

Comment: But the target tab would be the one to which the graphic (the source of the `dragDropped` event) belonged. You wouldn't need any additional listeners or logic to find it. See the answer I posted.

Comment: @n247s Thank you for that link, but I've already seen it before, it only provides moves to left and right, not drag and drop.

Comment: @James_D I'm gonna read your answer, thanks James.

Comment: I would recommend running it first, to see if it provides the functionality you're looking for. Then read the code if it does what you want.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the easiest way to approach this is to register the drag handlers with the graphic associated with the tab, instead of with the tab pane. This makes it a bit easier to manage the index of the tabs, etc, and you are not relying on the interplay between mouse drag actions and selection (you really have no idea what order those will happen in). The downside to this approach is that you somehow have to ensure that each tab *has* a graphic (you can use a label as the graphic to display text).

Here's a general purpose "tab pane dragging support" class. It is not meant to be production quality, by any means, but the basics seem to work. The idea here is that you create a `DraggingTabPaneSupport` instance and use it to add dragging support to one or more `TabPane`s. Tabs can then be dragged within or between any of those panes. If you want to be able to only drag within each tab pane, create a `DraggingTabPaneSupport` instance for each tab pane.

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener.Change;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.input.ClipboardContent;
import javafx.scene.input.Dragboard;
import javafx.scene.input.TransferMode;

public class DraggingTabPaneSupport {

    private Tab currentDraggingTab ;

    private static final AtomicLong idGenerator = new AtomicLong();

    private final String draggingID = "DraggingTabPaneSupport-"+idGenerator.incrementAndGet() ;

    public void addSupport(TabPane tabPane) {
        tabPane.getTabs().forEach(this::addDragHandlers);
        tabPane.getTabs().addListener((Change<? extends Tab> c) -> {
            while (c.next()) {
                if (c.wasAdded()) {
                    c.getAddedSubList().forEach(this::addDragHandlers);
                }
                if (c.wasRemoved()) {
                    c.getRemoved().forEach(this::removeDragHandlers);
                }
            }
        });

        // if we drag onto a tab pane (but not onto the tab graphic), add the tab to the end of the list of tabs:
        tabPane.setOnDragOver(e -> {
            if (draggingID.equals(e.getDragboard().getString()) && 
                    currentDraggingTab != null &&
                    currentDraggingTab.getTabPane() != tabPane) {
                e.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.MOVE);
            }
        });
        tabPane.setOnDragDropped(e -> {
            if (draggingID.equals(e.getDragboard().getString()) && 
                    currentDraggingTab != null &&
                    currentDraggingTab.getTabPane() != tabPane) {

                currentDraggingTab.getTabPane().getTabs().remove(currentDraggingTab);
                tabPane.getTabs().add(currentDraggingTab);
                currentDraggingTab.getTabPane().getSelectionModel().select(currentDraggingTab);
            }
        });
    }

    private void addDragHandlers(Tab tab) {

        // move text to label graphic:
        if (tab.getText() != null && ! tab.getText().isEmpty()) {
            Label label = new Label(tab.getText(), tab.getGraphic());
            tab.setText(null);
            tab.setGraphic(label);
        }

        Node graphic = tab.getGraphic();
        graphic.setOnDragDetected(e -> {
            Dragboard dragboard = graphic.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.MOVE);
            ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
            // dragboard must have some content, but we need it to be a Tab, which isn't supported
            // So we store it in a local variable and just put arbitrary content in the dragbaord:
            content.putString(draggingID);
            dragboard.setContent(content);
            dragboard.setDragView(graphic.snapshot(null, null));
            currentDraggingTab = tab ;
        });
        graphic.setOnDragOver(e -> {
            if (draggingID.equals(e.getDragboard().getString()) && 
                    currentDraggingTab != null &&
                    currentDraggingTab.getGraphic() != graphic) {
                e.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.MOVE);
            }
        });
        graphic.setOnDragDropped(e -> {
            if (draggingID.equals(e.getDragboard().getString()) && 
                    currentDraggingTab != null &&
                    currentDraggingTab.getGraphic() != graphic) {

                int index = tab.getTabPane().getTabs().indexOf(tab) ;
                currentDraggingTab.getTabPane().getTabs().remove(currentDraggingTab);
                tab.getTabPane().getTabs().add(index, currentDraggingTab);
                currentDraggingTab.getTabPane().getSelectionModel().select(currentDraggingTab);
            }
        });
        graphic.setOnDragDone(e -> currentDraggingTab = null);
    }

    private void removeDragHandlers(Tab tab) {
        tab.getGraphic().setOnDragDetected(null);
        tab.getGraphic().setOnDragOver(null);
        tab.getGraphic().setOnDragDropped(null);
        tab.getGraphic().setOnDragDone(null);
    }
}
```

Here's a quick example of using it. In this example I create three tab panes. I create one dragging support instance for the first two panes, so tabs can be dragged between those two, and a second dragging support instance for the third pane, so in the third pane tabs can be re-ordered by dragging but cannot be dragged to the other two panes.

```
import java.util.Random;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class DraggingTabPaneExample extends Application {

    private final Random rng = new Random();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TabPane[] panes = new TabPane[] {new TabPane(), new TabPane(), new TabPane() };
        VBox root = new VBox(10, panes);
        for (int i = 1 ; i <= 15; i++) {
            Tab tab = new Tab("Tab "+i);
            tab.setGraphic(new Rectangle(16, 16, randomColor()));
            Region region = new Region();
            region.setMinSize(100, 150);
            tab.setContent(region);
            panes[(i-1) % panes.length].getTabs().add(tab);
        }

        DraggingTabPaneSupport support1 = new DraggingTabPaneSupport();
        support1.addSupport(panes[0]);
        support1.addSupport(panes[1]);
        DraggingTabPaneSupport support2 = new DraggingTabPaneSupport();
        support2.addSupport(panes[2]);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private Color randomColor() {
        return Color.rgb(rng.nextInt(256), rng.nextInt(256), rng.nextInt(256));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Initial screenshot:

[image]

After dragging within panes:
[image]

You can also drag between the first two panes (but not between the third and any others):

[image]

Comment: Just tried it ; your code works perfectly, thanks a lot James. I'd be cool if you made a library out of it (I think you thought of it this way, since you called it `...Support`) and hosted it on Github, it could help many people to make draggable tabs with JavaFx.

Comment: @HachemBenyahia It's good practice to *always* try to write code as though you are creating a library. I'll think about it, but I'm not that happy with the way it modifies the tab's text and graphic in order to work - that's not very satisfactory behavior. Probably the appropriate way forward is to suggest a patch to the `TabPaneSkin`, but that might be quite a lot more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

For re-ordering tabs in the same `TabPane`, as of JavaFX 10 there is:
[`myTabPane.setTabDragPolicy(TabDragPolicy.REORDER);`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TabPane.html#setTabDragPolicy(javafx.scene.control.TabPane.TabDragPolicy))